# Is there any function in JS like this int.from_bytes() in Python?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know there is a built-in function in Python to convert a byte array to a single int value:

```
int_val = int.from_bytes(byte_arr, 'big')
```

Is there JS alternative?

I have a byte array, generated by nodejs module "hash.js". I would like to convert the output to a single int value as well.

```
const hash = require('hash.js')
let hash = hash.sha256().update(unescape(encodeURIComponent('abc')))
```

Is there a easy way to convert byte array in integer in JS, or I have to write my own function?

Comment: Depends. What format is your byte array in? For instance, many use cases of from_bytes use a hex value as the array, and in JS you can convert a hex value to a number using `parseInt` with a radix of 16. Other formats may have other solutions; so what format is your particular array representing?

Comment: It could be any, incl. hex. And I prefer to work with hex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const buf = Buffer.from([0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78]) // 0x12345678 = 305419896

console.log(buf.readUInt32BE(0)) // 305419896
```

Comment: Yes. It works. I spent hours looking up the web for a solution. But this works with hex as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the case `hash` is your byte array, I would try something like this:

```
const hash = require('hash.js')
let hash = hash.sha256().update(unescape(encodeURIComponent('abc')))


const buf = Buffer.from(hash)
// readIntLE is for little endian, use readIntBE otherwise
const myInt = buf.readIntLE(0, Buffer.byteLength(hash))
```

Check the [doc](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuintbe_offset_bytelength) for `readInt` methods

Answer (score 0):

Found a much better reliable way to do this (can change the encoding in case you prefer other encodings):

For big endian

```
function bigIntFromBytesBE(str) {
  return [...Buffer.from(str, 'binary')].map(
   (el, index, { length }) => {
     return BigInt(el * (256 ** (length - (1+index))))
   }).reduce((prev, curr) => {
     return prev + curr;
  }, BigInt(0));
}
```

For little endian:

```
function bigIntFromBytesLE(str) {
  return [...Buffer.from(str, 'binary')].map(
   (el, index) => {
     return BigInt(el * (256 ** index))
   }).reduce((prev, curr) => {
     return prev + curr;
  }, BigInt(0));
}
```